# IdentityServer 4 as a web API

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

How to use identity server 4 as a web API in .net core?

Is there any sample application available for the same.

On their sample application, they are redirecting to login page and then they authenticate.

I want to use service without redirecting to login page.

Answer (score 2):

You would require the api to be authenticated via IDS4, rather than not have a login page. You can either use a service account which is basically a user name and password with additional shared secret, or you can allow a client token to flow through and make calls on there behalf.

When making calls on behalf of you need to have offline_access to the token and deal with making calls with a refresh token, the link below has all the information you should need.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess

Comment: I need it to be called from javascript client. Can you please help?